# How do I fetch dynamically array of images based on id using explode function and prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Here, property_id is Integer and property_img is Varchar.

clicking on particular image(which is array of images),passing id through hyperlink ,it should show in form of carousel manner

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <?php 
 $sql="select property_id,property_img from img_tbl";

       $q=$conn->query($sql);
       if($q->num_rows>0)
       {
         while($r1=$q->fetch_assoc())
       {
            $property_img1=$r1['property_img'];
         $property_img=explode(' ',$property_img1);


        echo '

     <div id="shade">
     <div class="col-sm-12 " id="color">
     <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">    

     <div class="row fppadd"> 
     <span></i><a href="viewpro_img.php?propty_id='.$r1['property_id'].'">'; 
     ?>

     <img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/ <?php
        foreach($property_img as $data){
        echo '
        '.$data.'  '  ;
        }
        ?> "
        width="200" height="150"><br></a></span><br>
     </div>
                  </div>



  </div>

  </div> <?php
       }
       }?>       
       <br> 






  </form>
```

Please help.

---

Am getting this by view source But images not showing in Browser.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


     <div id="shade">
     <div class="col-sm-12 " id="color">
     <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">    

     <div class="row fppadd"> 
     <span></i><a href="viewpro_img.php?propty_id=13">
```

**this is the first array of image**

```
     <img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/ 
        a.jpg  
        avatar.png  
        b.jpg   "
        width="200" height="150"><br></a></span><br>
     </div>
                  </div>



  </div>

  </div> 

     <div id="shade">
     <div class="col-sm-12 " id="color">
     <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">    

     <div class="row fppadd"> 
     <span></i><a href="viewpro_img.php?propty_id=14">
```

**this is the 2nd array of image **

```
     <img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/ 
        Chrysanthemum.jpg  
        Desert.jpg  
        img02.jpg  
        img03.jpg  
        img05.jpg  
        img06.jpg  
        img07.jpg  
        img09.jpg  
        img10.jpg  
        img11.jpg   "
        width="200" height="150"><br></a></span><br>
     </div>
                  </div>



  </div>

  </div>        
       <br> 






  </form>
```

Comment: add `where property_id=<your id>`?

Comment: Please add the value of var_dump($r1) inside your while, we need to see exactly what you get back from the database.

Comment: @Nic ...Actually In DB one column having multiple Images eg. (a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg d.jpg). I am fetching these images using explode function but image name showing only when I inspect it not in Browser.

Comment: Try no2.  Does your code display anything in a browser?  If yes, please do a view source and add it to the question.  If not, what does the error log tell you?

Comment: @Nic I updated ..please check and try to resolve my issue

Comment: ah, each image needs it's own img tag.  You cannot have multiple images (i.e. files) inside the src portion of the img tag.  So for each image, you must output the entire img tag (with class, src, and alt).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/ <?php
    foreach($property_img as $data){
    echo '
    '.$data.'  '  ;
    }
    ?> "
    width="200" height="150"
```

Do this:

```
foreach ($property_img as $data)
{
    echo "<img class=\"img-zoom\" src=\"uploads/" . $data . "\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\" alt=\"something\">
}
```

Your resulting HTML will look like

```
<img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/IMG1.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="something" >
<img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/IMG2.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="something" >
<img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/IMG3.jpg" width="200" height="150" alt="something" >
```

...

Comment: am getting the same output as yours But only first image fetching and others displaying 'something' . please check inside the explode function becoz I inserted the image using implode function so its in form of array. please try to resolve it soon.

Comment: The easiest way would be to accept this answer and post a new question with the code and the result of "view source" from the browser.  Also display the visual result and what you expect that is different.